# Escape ruby code inside HTML string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object in my controller

```
@data="<meta property=\"og:url\"
             content=\"<%=SITE_URL%><%=request.request_uri%>\"
      />".html_safe
```

When I print this in my view file by <%=@data%> the html that it generates is

```
<meta property="og:url" 
      content="<%=SITE_URL%><%=request.request_uri%>"
/>
```

How do i print out/escape the ruby code withing the string?

Comment: 19 questions, 0 accepted answers - wow!

Comment: come on you need to accept answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for string interpolation, which means that in the string, it substitutes the value of the variable. Surround the variables with #{} like this:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation

```
@data="<meta property=\"og:url\"
         content=\"#{SITE_URL} #{request.request_uri}\"
  />".html_safe
```

Now, when you do `<%= @data %>`, it should show up normally.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to write `#{SITE_URL}` instead of `<%= #{SITE_URL}%>`? The second one still has erb`s interpolation method in it. I do not dare to edit your question without permission ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try h helper like this.....

```
   <%=h(@data)  %>
```

also raw can be use

```
    <%=raw(@data) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@data="<meta property=\"og:url\"
         content=\"<%= #{SITE_URL}%><%= #{request.request_uri} %>\"
  />"
```

In your views use raw helper method

```
<%= raw(@data) %>
```